# How do I fire a tag in GTM when a value appears in my data layer?

Tags: google-tag-manager

My website loads values into my data layer after the website loads. I'd like to fire tags when certain values appear in my data layer, and incorporate my data layer items into the tag (for example, an order id).

How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are doing a "push" to the dataLayer. Push a variable with the key "event" along with your orderid:

```
dataLayer.push({
'orderid' : '12345',
'event' : 'myEvent'
});
```

Then create a trigger type `custom event` where "`event name equals myEvent`' and use this to trigger your tag:

[image]

Comment: Is this setup correct? http://i.imgur.com/9kVfh1V.png My tag still isn't firing with this logic =(

Comment: @SRUCLA, this isn't correct - you need to set "Event Name" to the name of your custom event ("myEvent" in the example). The event name field takes the value that is assigned to the event key in the dataLayer; plus gtm.dom happens only once after the DOM has rendered, so you cannot use it to fire data that was inserted later.

Comment: @SRUCLA, I added a screenshot.