# Google Tag Manager with Ajax form - how to fire on response

Tags: google-tag-manager

I am having trouble using Google Tag Manager with a one page website and an ajax contact form.

I've been looking at old articles and examples and newer ones but none of them are for using an ajax form. I've seen an example using V1 where they use virtual page views but I can't find how to do this in V2.

What I need it to do is to fire off an event when the form successfully gets submitted.  I can't use a button click as the form has validation.

```
<body id="page-top" class="index">
    <script>
        dataLayer = [];
    </script>
    <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
    .....
    .....
    .....
    <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
    <!-- Navigation -->
```

Once the form is valid, in my jquery ajax success, i push to the dataLayer some values that I want to pass to GTM.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "........",
    type: "POST",
    data: {........},
    success: function() {
        dataLayer.push({
            'event':'pageview',
            'virtualUrl':'/success/' 
        });
    }
});
```

What I'm looking for is an example if anyone has done this before or how to get this working as my triggers never fire

I was looking at this as it seems close to what i want to achieve [How do I fire a tag in GTM when a value appears in my data layer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30360805/how-do-i-fire-a-tag-in-gtm-when-a-value-appears-in-my-data-layer/)

Comment: Actually I have done this before in exactly the same way as described in the answer you have linked. If i had to guess (and I apologize in advance if I'm wrong) I'd say you somehow expect an Analytics tag to fire automatically when you name your event "pageview", but that's not how it works - you still need to set up a custom event in GTM (and pass your virtualUrl as a variable to the pagePath field).